# Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail html tags not working

Tags: html, perl, email

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $mail=Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail->new( -smtp=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                                            -login=>'sample@gmail.com',
                                            -pass=>'password');
my $body = '<h1>buddy I got it ...</h1>';
$mail->send(-to=>'to@gmail.com',-cc=>'',-subject=>'subject',
            -body=>$body,-contenttype=>'text/html');
$mail->bye;
```

[Everytime i run my script here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8BhF.png)

Can somebody suggest and help me out why is that my html (body email )not working .

Comment: `my $body ='<h1>buddy I got it . . . </h1>';`

Answer (score 0):

You are placing HTML code inside the content of a plain text email.
This module doesn't seem to support HTML emails... you must provide the headers yourself if you whant to send HTML in your email, or find a module that does it for you.

The key:  **-contenttype=>'text/html'**  most likely is being ignored... it is not mentioned in the module docs!